# How will union mounts be possible in 12.04?

Tags: mount, filesystem, 12.04, unionfs

I noticed today that Ubuntu 12.04 will [not](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/linux-image-3.2.0-17-generic/filelist) include [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs3/man.html).

What, if anything, will be available to facilitate the creation of [union mounts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement for `aufs` in 12.04 is `overlayfs`.

In case you're interested, these sorts of things are decided at the "kernel delta review" and "kernel config review" sessions at each UDS. In this case, notes are at:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/Specs/PreciseKernelDeltaReview