# How do I use OverlayFS?

Tags: filesystem, overlayfs

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/109311/1859) and [email message](http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/RFC-AUFS-disabled-for-12-04-td4532154.html) indicate that something called "OverlayFS" is available in Ubuntu 11.10 and will forcefully replace aufs in Ubuntu 12.04.

How do I use it? Where is its documentation?

Comment: You and me both, brother. I've come across this so far: `mount -t overlayfs -o rw,uppderdir=x,lowerdir=y overlayfs /mount/point`. Beyond that I'm clueless. I'm tinkering with it in a live system, but I haven't managed to get it to to work yet. I wish I could find out exactly what "upperdir" and "lowerdir" mean. I've found nothing.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Edit: Since writing this answer, some things have changed in overlayfs, namely the addition of a required parameter `workdir`, see [totti's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/487085/43483) below for a detailed description of this new parameter.

I finally managed to find it. I found references to it in the kernel source, but for some reason it doesn't appear in the git tree on kernel.org. But! If you pull the Ubuntu kernel source like this: `apt-get source linux-image-3.0.0-16-generic` you can find it in `linux-3.0.0/Documentation/overlayfs.txt`.  It is also available in the linux-doc package in `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/filesystems/overlayfs.txt.gz`.

As the actual help documentation is more of a "how it works" instead of a "how to mount with it," here's a brief rundown (there is one example in the kernel documentation):

```
mount -t overlayfs -o [mount options] overlayfs [mountpoint for merged system]
```

Where [mount options] can be:

- lowerdir=somedir: lowerdir is the directory you're going to lay your new filesystem over, if there are duplicates these get overwritten by (actually, hidden in favor of) upperdir's version
- upperdir=somedir: upperdir is the directory you want to overlay lowerdir with. If duplicate filenames exist in lowerdir and upperdir, upperdir's version takes precedence.
- standard mount options. The only one I've seen from code is ro/rw, but you can experiment.

One thing that confused me at first, so I should probably clarify, is that mounting an overlayfs does not actually mount a filesystem. I was trying to mount a squashfs filesystem using an overlayfs mount, but that's not how it works. You must first mount the (in my case squashfs) filesystem to an arbitrary directory, then use overlayfs to merge the mount point (a directory) and another directory onto a tertiary directory (the overlayfs mount point)(edit: this "tertiary" directory can actually be the upperdir= directory). The tertiary directory is where you will see the merged filesystems (or directory trees - it's flexible).

#### Example 1, overlaying the root filesystem

I've been working on an Ubuntu hybrid boot disk where the base Ubuntu system exists as filesystem.squashfs and I have files called ubuntu.overlay kubuntu.overlay xubuntu.overlay and lubuntu.overlay. The .overlay files are base installs of said systems with the contents of filesystem.squashfs pruned (to save space). Then I modified the init scripts to overlay the correct distro's .overlay file (from a boot parameter) using overlayfs and the above options and it works like a charm!

These are the lines that I used in my init scripts (once all variables are translated):

```
mkdir -p /overlay
mount -t squashfs /cdrom/casper/ubuntu.overlay /overlay
mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=/filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/overlay overlayfs /
```

Note that filesystem.squashfs above is a *directory* created by casper, not a file.

These three statements create an `/overlay` directory, mount a squashfs filesystem on the `/overlay` directory and then use OverlayFS to essentially merge the contents of `/overlay` over `/`.

#### Example 2, transparent merging of two directories

In the process of re-building my live USB for each release, I use OverlayFS to save a bunch of time. I start off with a directory called ubuntu-base which contains the contents of the ubuntu-core image which is the most basic install. I will then create directories called ubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu, and xubuntu.

Then, I use OverlayFS to make the files from the ubuntu-base show up in the individual directories. I would use something like this:

```
mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=ubuntu-base,upperdir=kubuntu overlayfs kubuntu
```

This makes the files from ubuntu-base show up in the kubuntu folder. Then, I can `chroot` to the kubuntu folder and do something like `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. Any changes that are made while in this OverlayFS mount will remain in the upper directory, in this case the kubuntu folder. Then, once I unmount the OverlayFS mount the files that really exist in ubuntu-base but are "mirrored" into the kubuntu folder vanish unless they have been changed. This keeps me from having to have multiple copies of the files in ubuntu-base while still being able to use them as if they physically exist in each location.

Comment: It was in the documentation as described above. It gave one example and I just extrapolated off it. The documentation gives a very deep explanation of how the filesystem itself works.

Comment: *"but for some reason it doesn't appear in the git tree on kernel.org"* - That's because overlayfs is not in upstream kernel, just like aufs isn't (and won't ever be). Such union filesystems are integrated by Ubuntu Kernel Team.

Comment: OverlayFS is apparently getting into kernel 3.10.

Comment: Finally, should go in 3.18 http://lwn.net/Articles/617099/

Comment: Bug in example `mount -t overlayfs lowerdir=ubuntu-base,upperdir=kubuntu overlayfs kubuntu` should be `mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=ubuntu-base,upperdir=kubuntu overlayfs kubuntu`

Comment: what about `workdir`?

Comment: @Rmano: on my machine it works only with `overlay` not with `overlayfs`

Comment: @DustWolf, saw that yesterday and fixed it =)

Comment: @Rmano, if you mean the last part of the mount where it says "overlayfs (some directory)", indeeed you are correct. If I'm not mistaking you can put anything there.

Comment: Since being merged into the mainline kernel the options have changed, see other answer below http://askubuntu.com/a/487085/15168

Comment: Thank you @austinmarton, I found this a while back too and totti covered it below before I updated my answer, so I gave credit to his answer at the top of mine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=/filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/overlay overlayfs /` command? Are actually able to replace `/` on a working system? What happens to current processes (and their offsprings)? What happens to currently open files?

Comment: That is effectively what the Ubuntu livecd does. It mounts filesystem.squashfs into a folder, mount --binds /proc /sys /dev, etc. And then chroots into the directory. A more direct / overlay should still work, since all files underneath the overlay are still readable and wires get sent to the upperdir instead of /

Answer (score 27):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt:

> ### Upper and Lower
>
> An overlay filesystem combines two filesystems - an 'upper' filesystem
>   and a 'lower' filesystem.  When a name exists in both filesystems, the
>   object in the 'upper' filesystem is visible while the object in the
>   'lower' filesystem is either hidden or, in the case of directories,
>   merged with the 'upper' object.
>
> It would be more correct to refer to an upper and lower 'directory
>   tree' rather than 'filesystem' as it is quite possible for both
>   directory trees to be in the same filesystem and there is no
>   requirement that the root of a filesystem be given for either upper or
>   lower.
>
> The lower filesystem can be any filesystem supported by Linux and does
>   not need to be writable.  The lower filesystem can even be another
>   overlayfs.  The upper filesystem will normally be writable and if it
>   is it must support the creation of trusted.* extended attributes, and
>   must provide valid d_type in readdir responses, so NFS is not suitable.
>
> A read-only overlay of two read-only filesystems may use any
>   filesystem type.
>
> ### Directories
>
> Overlaying mainly involves directories.  If a given name appears in both
>   upper and lower filesystems and refers to a non-directory in either,
>   then the lower object is hidden - the name refers only to the upper
>   object.
>
> Where both upper and lower objects are directories, a merged directory
>   is formed.
>
> At mount time, the two directories given as mount options "lowerdir" and
>   "upperdir" are combined into a merged directory:
>
> ```
> mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper,workdir=/work /merged
> ```
>
> The "workdir" needs to be an empty directory on the same filesystem
>   as upperdir.
>
> Then whenever a lookup is requested in such a merged directory, the
>   lookup is performed in each actual directory and the combined result
>   is cached in the dentry belonging to the overlay filesystem.  If both
>   actual lookups find directories, both are stored and a merged
>   directory is created, otherwise only one is stored: the upper if it
>   exists, else the lower.
>
> Only the lists of names from directories are merged.  Other content
>   such as metadata and extended attributes are reported for the upper
>   directory only.  These attributes of the lower directory are hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on workdir. That was a fairly recent change and for whatever reason I was never able to find any documentation about what 'workdir' actually did. It wasn't in the kernel help either last time I looked. Adds a layer of confusion to overlayfs IMO, wish the newer versions could be used without it -- it kind of messes up my workflow.

Comment: I read this, as I was told that it has a clarification on what the working directory is. But don't see one. (is in just the backing store for the cache that you talk about? So can be removed when the FS is offline, but help performance? Or does it contain primary data?)

Answer (score 8):

**Minimal runnable example**

```
# Create the filesystems.
dd if=/dev/zero of=lower.ext4 bs=1024 count=102400
mkfs -t ext4 lower.ext4
cp lower.ext4 upper.ext4
mkdir lower upper overlay
sudo mount lower.ext4 lower
sudo mount upper.ext4 upper
sudo chown "$USER:$USER" lower upper
printf lower-content > lower/lower-file
# Upper and work must be on the same filesystem.
mkdir upper/upper upper/work
printf upper-content > upper/upper/upper-file
# Work must be empty. E.g. this would be bad:
#printf work-content > upper/work/work-file
# Make the lower readonly to show that that is possible:
# writes actually end up on the upper filesystem.
sudo mount -o remount,ro lower.ext4 lower

# Create the overlay mount.
sudo mount \
  -t overlay \
  -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper/upper,workdir=upper/work \
  none \
  overlay \
;

# Interact with the mount.
printf 'overlay-content' > overlay/overlay-file
ls lower upper/upper upper/work overlay

# Write to underlying directories while mounted
# gives undefined behaviour.
#printf lower-content-2 > lower/lower-file-2
#printf upper-content-2 > upper/upper-file-2

# Unmount the overlay and observe state.
sudo umount overlay
ls lower upper/upper upper/work

# Cleanup.
sudo umount upper lower
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/adc3b4660642e65b8146dddce57ddc3e56f53029/overlayfs.sh).

Output of the first `ls` with the mount:

```
lower:
lost+found  lower-file

overlay:
lost+found  lower-file  overlay-file  upper-file

upper/upper:
overlay-file  upper-file

upper/work:
work
```

Output of the second `ls` without the mount:

```
lower:
lost+found  lower-file

upper/upper:
overlay-file  upper-file

upper/work:
work
```

Interpretation:

- lower: was unchanged after writing to overlay
- upper: received the modification to overlay
- overlay: shows files from both upper and lower
- work: contains some random content (a `work/` directory) we should not care about

Example adapted from: [Example OverlayFS Usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699565/example-overlayfs-usage/704358#704358)

Here is a more complex example with multiple lower layers: [Overlayfs reload with multiple layers (migration away from aufs)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143176/overlayfs-reload-with-multiple-layers-migration-away-from-aufs/1083452#1083452)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, Linux kernel 4.15.0.

Answer (score 7):

I have extended these artikels to include a Script for overlayfs that sets up a read-only root fs.

- English: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash
- German: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Nur-Lesen_Root-Dateisystem

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks to the work that others did, Dustin and I have added a banary package named 'overlayroot' to quantal, which is part of the [cloud-initramfs-tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-initramfs-tools) source package.  See usage documentation in [/etc/overlayroot.conf](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/quantal/cloud-initramfs-tools/quantal/view/head:/overlayroot/etc/overlayroot.conf)

Answer (score 2):

### Mounting OverlayFS in fstab

Above answers have explained how to mount overlay filesystem from cmd line and/or script. It is also possible to mount OverlayFS from **fstab**.

There is inherent problem with mounting OverlayFS. Since we mount directories, those directories must be present and/or ready. Present means that filesystem on which particular directory is located is already mounted, while ready means that particular directory is "populated". Example of later is mounting of ISO image to particular directory, or mounting network share (of any type).

Mounting directory which is not present, will fail, while mounting not yet "populated" directory will not fail, since OverlayFS has no way to know, if directory is ready.

When mounting filesystems from fstab, that is particularly a problem, since all mounting is done in parallel, thus we can not ensure that everything is prepared for OverlayFS.

However, if Linux distribution uses systemd, than mounting of filesystems is handled by it. Systemd reads fstab file, and creates mount units on the fly. After that all mounting is processed by systemd. Systemd unit files have options: r**equire**, **after**, **before**, which can be used to control the order and dependency of mounts defined in fstab, thus ensuring that mounting of OverlayFS will not fail (at least not, because of wrong order).

To set order/dependency of mounts in fstab file, we will declare systemd option "**require**" using syntax: **x-systemd.require**. Argument for this option is mount point of the mount which should be successfully mounted before given mount (defined in fstab).

### Example:

To show an example (and syntax of **fstab** entries), we will show case, where we will overlay directory on which iso image is mounted, while this particular image file will be stored on separate hdd, which will have to be mounted before we access image file. Thus forming required ordered of events:

```
mount hdd -> mount iso image -> mount OverlayFS
```

For given case fstab entries would look like:

```
# 1. mount hdd partition
# 2. mount iso image from hdd partition, but only if/after hdd is mounted
# 3. overlay iso image, but only if/after iso image is mounted
#
/dev/hdb1            /mnt/hdd      ext4     errors=remount-ro                 0  2  
/mnt/hdd/linux.iso   /mnt/iso      auto     x-systemd.requires=/mnt/hdd,ro    0  0
overlay              /mnt/merged   overlay  x-systemd.requires=/mnt/iso,lowerdir=/mnt/iso,upperdir=/overlay/lower,workdir=/overlay/working  0 0
```

If any mounts in chain fail, dependent one(s) will not be executed.

### Note:

On [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Overlay_filesystem) there is example of using fstab to mount OverlayFS in which following options are used:

```
noauto,x-systemd.automount
```

This will have effect, that overlay filesystem will be simply **not mounted** at boot time (***noauto*** option), avoiding possible failure if previous mounts are not ready. On first access to overlay directory, the filesystem will be mounted (***x-systemd.automount*** option). This approach has two weaknesses:

1. If needed lower/upper directories are not ready this mount will fail.
2. Mount will succeed even if lower/upper directories are not populated (ISO is not mounted f.e.)

We can avoid later, by adding **x-systemd.require** to the options list.