# What is the difference between kernel 3.16 and 3.18?

Tags: kernel

It is appreciated to keep the release date of 15.04.

The update from 14.10 to 15.04 has been processed successfully.

It is found that the main homepage of Ubuntu is changed, which is more attractive than before, I think.

I wonder what is improved or renewed by kernel update from 3.16 to 3.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many things change, and too many changes are of a highly technical nature for a good answer. I will try to highlight a couple of things, but you can get a good summary at Kernel Newbies ([3.17](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.17), [3.18](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.18)).

- OverlayFS
  The big change, for me, was the merge of [OverlayFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) to the mainline kernel in 3.18. OverlayFS is a lightweight way to obtain a "merged" view of two directories. Uses including having a combined view of [your media files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179404/70524), [safely running scripts in sandbox](https://askubuntu.com/a/548712/158442), etc.
- Thunderbolt and XBox One controller support
- Signed kexec kernels - `kexec` is a feature that allows you to upgrade 
  the kernel without a full reboot.