# Overlayfs to an existing directory

Tags: mount, overlayfs

I have looked at 
[How do I use OverlayFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs?newreg=2ac1c691a94b4e998883f958369b5f5c) but it doesn't answer my question.

I need to install some third party applications and they require `/opt` to be writable but the device I am running on has `/opt` on a readable rootfs. Essentially, I have a directory `/opt` on a read-only filesystem (lower) and let's say I have a read-write directory `/mnt/optw` (writable). I would like to merge `/opt` & `/mnt/optw` and mount it to `/opt`.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved through kernel in-built `overlayfs` module:

```
# mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/opt,upperdir=/mnt/optw,workdir=/tmp/opt-overlay overlay /opt
```

That can be checked to be properly mounted as:

```bash
$ mount | tail -1
overlay on /opt type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/opt,upperdir=/mnt/optw,workdir=/tmp/opt-overlay)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind `/mnt/optw` to `/opt` like so:

```
sudo mount --bind /mnt/optw/ /opt/
```

This way `/opt` will be a reflection of `/mnt/optw` contents and permissions.

---

To access the contents of the two directories under `/opt`, mount with `aufs` like so:

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br=/opt/:/mnt/optw/ none /opt/
```

This way, the two directories are merged and you'll be able to access their contents under `/opt/`.

**Notice**:

If you do not have `aufs` support available on your system, you can add support by installing `aufs-tools` like so:

```
sudo apt install aufs-tools
```

For further reading [man aufs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/aufs.5.html).

---

**Edit:**

Regarding the OP's comment, The same can be achieved through kernel in-built `overlayfs` module:

```bash
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/opt,upperdir=/mnt/optw,workdir=/tmp/optoverlay overlay /opt
```

Comment: But the contents of original /opt are not visible as this straightforward mount. I would like the contents of /opt and /mnt/optw both be visible, ie, merged. I thought we might need something like overlayfs

Comment: @zenDev120 OK. I will update the answer for that. One moment please

Comment: Thanks for the updated comment and that's precisely what I need but my rootfs doesn't have support for aufs but only overlayfs.  Do you know if it is possible to achieve similar result with overlayfs?

Comment: @zenDev120 I updated the answer and added instructions for installing aufs. Best of luck