# How to move available space from / (root) to /home? (Ubuntu server 18:04 LTS)

Tags: partitioning, raid

I just got a new ubuntu 18.04 server with two hard drives of 4TB each, with RAID. Ubuntu was set up automatically on it. Looking at it now, I see this:

```
root@host ~ # lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0   32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0   32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0  512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  511M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda3    8:3    0    2T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0    2T  0 raid1 /
├─sda4    8:4    0  1.7T  0 part
│ └─md3   9:3    0  1.7T  0 raid1 /home
└─sda5    8:5    0    1M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0   32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0   32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0  512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  511M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb3    8:19   0    2T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0    2T  0 raid1 /
├─sdb4    8:20   0  1.7T  0 part
│ └─md3   9:3    0  1.7T  0 raid1 /home
└─sdb5    8:21   0    1M  0 part
```

I'd prefer `/home` to have almost all the space that now sits in '/' (root), as that's where all the websites etc will be in.

How do I do that using the command line? Do I have to make the changes on both disk or does that happen automagically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**One way** is this:

You could create a directory under `/` like so:

```
sudo mkdir /free_space
```

Then, create a directory under your home directory like so:

```
mkdir ~/free_space
```

Then bind the `/free_space` directory to `~/free_space` directory like so:

```
sudo mount --bind /free_space ~/free_space
```

This way all the free space on `/` will be accessible under `~/free_space`

**Another way** would be to use [aufs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222054/968501) to merge `/free_space` with your home directory.