# Moving space from /home partition to others

Tags: partitioning

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a 1TB NVMe, and the partitioning looks as follows

[image]

I have only allocated 512 to Swap when installing Ubuntu (followed some random guide on the internet) but while I'm working, I notice the swap gets full quite quickly. I thought about expanding it a bit - maybe to match my RAM size.

As can be seen, I have plenty of space on my `/home` partition (Partition3) and I'd like to take some space from there and move it to my swap. Actually I'd also like to add some to Filesystem root if possible.

But when I right click the Partition and try to resize it down by few GB, I get the following error:

[image]

So how can I move space from Partition 3 to partition 2 and 1?

Comment: An alternative way without partitioning would be [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165500/968501) for swap and something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235357/968501) for reassigning free space.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot resize a partition that's mounted, and you cannot unmount a partition that's in use. The best way to do this would be to boot from a USB Stick (or Live DVD) and resize the partitions from there via GParted.

Comment: Well I successfully downsized Partition 3 using the USB Ubuntu - but I couldn't expand Partition 1 and Partition 2 with the space that was left... Moreover Ubuntu wouldn't boot after that. I tried going into safe mode and updating grub, that didn't work either. I ended up formatting the entire NVMe and reinstalling Ubuntu