# Can someone help me either to extend /dev/sda2 partition or to reroute stuff to other partitions?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, xserver, disk-management, tmp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz7O4.jpg)I often get a message saying 'unable to write to /tmp' as /dev/sda2 run out of space. I don't have any free space left to create a logical volume. I was wondering if I could extend the volume of /dev /sda2 without having to format any other partitions. Or if I could reroute anything coming in /dev/sda2's way to /dev/sda4 i just don't know how to.
(Please excuse my mistakes that I might have committed while initially creating the partitions)

Comment: Related: [How to move available space from / (root) to /home? (Ubuntu server 18:04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1235188/968501)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move available space from / (root) to /home? (Ubuntu server 18:04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235188/how-to-move-available-space-from-root-to-home-ubuntu-server-1804-lts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)