# How to give space for sda2 from sda4(/dos)

Tags: boot, 22.04, files, filesystem, disk-usage

I have got too much not used space in sda4(/dos) folder

[image: sda 4 Usage]

But, actually my space in sda2 is about to end :(

[image: sda 2 Usage]

So, the question is: Is there a way to make available space for sda4 from 90GB to for example 10GB, and give that 80GB space for sda2?

[image: System Monitor/File Systems]

Comment: Screenshot the *entire* gparted window.  Because you can't directly do that, you have to resize sda4, then move sda3 over to where the empty space is, and then expand sda2 and it has a high risk of data loss.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It’s not possible to answer without more information, but have a look here - does that help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: Other than resizing partitions, you can also try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1235357