# many configuration removed after reboot

Tags: partitioning, mount, reboot

I am using Ubuntu 20.10, and many configuration are being removed after the reboot, like disk mount and proxy settings, and I have to re-apply them everytime, I am worried this might broke something in the files.

Is there anyway to permanently save the config?

> df -kh

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 1.7M | 2.8G | 1% | /run |
| /dev/sda3 | 294G | 12G | 268G | 5% | / |
| tmpfs | 14G | 0 | 14G | 0% | /dev/shm |
| tmpfs | 5.0M | 0 | 5.0M | 0% | /run/lock |
| tmpfs | 4.0M | 0 | 4.0M | 0% | /sys/fs/cgroup |
| /dev/sda2 | 512M | 7.9M | 505M | 2% | /boot/efi |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 132K | 2.8G | 1% | /run/user/126 |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 96K | 2.8G | 1% | /run/user/0 |
| /dev/sdc | 295G | 26G | 254G | 10% | /media/cases2 |
| /dev/sdb | 295G | 259G | 21G | 93% | /media/cases |
| /media/cases;/media/cases2 | 589G | 285G | 275G | 51% | /work |

> Reboot

> df -kh

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 1.7M | 2.8G | 1% | /run |
| /dev/sda3 | 294G | 12G | 268G | 5% | / |
| tmpfs | 14G | 0 | 14G | 0% | /dev/shm |
| tmpfs | 5.0M | 0 | 5.0M | 0% | /run/lock |
| tmpfs | 4.0M | 0 | 4.0M | 0% | /sys/fs/cgroup |
| /dev/sda2 | 512M | 7.9M | 505M | 2% | /boot/efi |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 132K | 2.8G | 1% | /run/user/126 |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 96K | 2.8G | 1% | /run/user/0 |

> Fix

> mount /dev/sdc /media/cases2

> mount /dev/sdb /media/cases/

> mhddfs /media/cases,/media/cases2  /work/

> df -kh

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 1.7M | 2.8G | 1% | /run |
| /dev/sda3 | 294G | 12G | 268G | 5% | / |
| tmpfs | 14G | 0 | 14G | 0% | /dev/shm |
| tmpfs | 5.0M | 0 | 5.0M | 0% | /run/lock |
| tmpfs | 4.0M | 0 | 4.0M | 0% | /sys/fs/cgroup |
| /dev/sda2 | 512M | 7.9M | 505M | 2% | /boot/efi |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 132K | 2.8G | 1% | /run/user/126 |
| tmpfs | 2.8G | 96K | 2.8G | 1% | /run/user/0 |
| /dev/sdc | 295G | 26G | 254G | 10% | /media/cases2 |
| /dev/sdb | 295G | 259G | 21G | 93% | /media/cases |
| /media/cases;/media/cases2 | 589G | 285G | 275G | 51% | /work |

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli here


 more /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=12ff0861-57e3-4b4b-9c4f-9f9971b662fa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation


UUID=49E6-3F3D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1


/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have fixed the entries inside the fstab now, and I can see the two disks after the reboot, is there a way to auto mount the directory /work which is a combination of the two directories?

Comment: There you go. The devices you’re mounting after boot are not in your `/etc/fstab` file. Have the devices mount at boot and create a startup script that runs `mhddfs` when you sign in (or look at using an LVM to automate this) 

Comment: "is there a way to auto mount the directory /work which is a combination of the two directories?"... try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1222054/968501